# GCP API key is not valid in postman

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I tried to create new dialogflow intent through postman. It is working in API Explorer but I can't able to connect dialogflow with postman. For doing this I have created some credentials,

1. New API key in GCP project
2. Oauth credentials in GCP project
3. Bearer token from google cloud SDK shell

Here I have used same API in postman but can't able to connect. How can I troubleshoot this?

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
                "reason": "API_KEY_INVALID",
                "domain": "googleapis.com",
                "metadata": {
                    "service": "dialogflow.googleapis.com"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to first register the postman Callback URL in your OAuth Client ID settings in order to use Postman with Google Cloud API's

Comment: where do you put the API key?

Comment: What commands did you use to pass API key?